# how to speed up or use parallel execution using tftpget when downloading files from the ftp site? talend

Tags: java, talend, jobs

I am observing that when use tftpconnection->tftpftilelist->tftpfileproperties-tbufferoutput/input->tmap->tftpget (sort the entire list of files in the remote ftp site lets say if it has 3000 odd files,it will sort and pull only the latest date (1 day date range)recent files) but since the files are around 100 MB each,i am observing it is taking forever to download 100 bytes per 5 second and takes quite a while to download to the local.

Is there any way to make the file download faster using tftpget or by enabling parallel execution,but i am noticing that the button is switched off or grayed out.

Please suggest?[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug : there is no variable attached to "Enable parallel execution" (it does not appear while hovering the text, and there is nothing related in the attached XML file of the component). It does not seem to be possible right now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying ,even i was wondering the same,but are you aware of any mechanism by which we can enable parallel execution when downloading the files and the contents are being transferred in the destination folder to happen synchronously rather than waiting for one file to be downloaded and then moving onto the next one in sequence